# Jenkins "Git Parameter" plugin with "useRepository" option

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using "Git Parameter" [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/) to allow users to pick branch\tag for configured repositories.

This plugin has "[useRepository](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/#use-repository)" option to allow linking with the configured repos in the "Pipeline script from SCM" option:

[image]

This assumes that i need to preconfigure some repos in the Jenkins pipeline (in the Jenkins UI) to be able to use "Git Parameter" plugin in the pipelines.

But i want to dynamically predefine list of repos from the pipeline code itself, without any configuration in the "Pipeline script from SCM" section.
Unfortunately this doesn't work.

I'm tried to add "checkout" block with "GitSCM" class before calling "gitParameter" but with no success.

Code example:

```
def app_components = [
    BACKEND        : ["NAME": "backend", "GIT": "ssh://git@xxx.local/_git/backend"],
    FRONTEND       : ["NAME": "frontend", "GIT": "ssh://git@xxx.local/_git/fronend"]
]
pipeline {
    agent any
 
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    dynamicParameters = []
                    app_components.eachWithIndex { name, components, index ->
                        checkout([
                            $class: 'GitSCM',
                            branches: [[name: '*/master']],
                            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                            extensions: [[$class: 'CleanCheckout']],
                            submoduleCfg: [],
                            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'XXX', url: components.GIT]]
                        ])
                        dynamicParameters << gitParameter(name: 'BRANCH_' + name, defaultValue: 'develop', quickFilterEnabled: true, type: 'PT_BRANCH_TAG', listSize: '10', useRepository: components.GIT)
                    }
                   
                    def userInput = input(
                     id: 'userInput', message: 'Test message:?',
                     parameters: dynamicParameters
                    )
                    println(userInput);
                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Git parameters text fields are always empty:

[image]

Could you advice some solution in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Play around with adding

```
gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)',
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).